# d6 delta query - get the latest entry

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I'm working on a query but I'm running into an issue with deltas and getting the latest info. If I have a table as such....

```
ID | fieldval | delta
1  |        1 |     0
1  |        0 |     1
2  |        1 |     0
2  |        0 |     1
3  |          |     0
3  |        0 |     1
3  |          |     2
```

I'd like to get results like:

```
ID | fieldval | delta
1  |        0 |     1
2  |        0 |     1
3  |        0 |     2
```

I want the latest delta that has a value per ID. I'm writing this in postgres but running into some issues. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand the logic for rows.  Please explain "I want the latest delta that has a value per ID" and how `0` is the value for each of the three rows in the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the largest `delta` with a value using `distinct on` and filtering:

```
select distinct on (id) t.*
from t
where fieldval is not null
order by id, delta desc;
```

However this does not return exactly the results you have specified.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, you can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (id) t.*
from mytable t
order by id, delta desc
```